# Running into issues getting os.rename module to work for automation script

Tags: python, file, networking, automation, file-manipulation

Im looping through a file with multiple log files that have been assigned a randomized filename. The script should search within the log for the line containing "hostname" and then pull out the assigned hostname to use as the re-assigned file name, which is where im having trouble...total noob....

```
  import os

path = "/Users/Joel/Desktop/logs"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(f"{path}/{file}") as log:
        for line in log:
            if "hostname" in line:
                desired_filename = line.split()[1].replace('"','')
                os.rename(f'{path}/{file}', f'{path}/{desired_filename}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(f"{path}/{file}") as file:
```

Using `file` as a variable name in the second line replaces the same variable from the first line.  You probably want to use different names for these two variables.

```
        os.rename(file, desired_filename)
```

You probably need to add `path` to the front of both of these filenames.

Comment: `os.rename(path(file), path(desired_filename))`    not sure if this is what you mean but it is erroring : 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That's not what I meant.  `file` does not live in the current directory; it lives in the `path` directory.  So you have to add `path` to the filename.

Comment: File "c:\Users\Joel\Desktop\python_work\exercises\rename_script.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.rename(f'{path}/{file}', f'{path}/{desired_filename}')
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '/Users/Joel/Desktop/logs/file1.txt' -> '/Users/Joel/Desktop/logs/MDF-1234'

Comment: You're trying to move `file` while you still have it open in the `with open ...` block.

Comment: man...i might be over my head with this lol....so `file.close()` somewhere in the loop?

Comment: Edit the question to include your updated code that fixes the first problem in my answer.  I have to see that before I can fix this latest issue.